# Search in sequelize where (column1 + column2 +column3) <= column4

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I need to run this SQL query in sequelize:

`SELECT * FROM db.table WHERE (attr1 + attr2 + attr3) <= attr4;`

I've been trying and searching for hours but I'm unable. Can anyone help me please?

Comment: What DBMS do you use?

Comment: I use MySQLWorkbench.

Comment: And this is the exact query in SQL which works in MySQLWorkbench: 
SELECT * FROM vs_app_demoes.order_planned
WHERE (contstation0 + disponiblestation1 + disponiblestation2) <= units;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way is to use `sequelize.literal` to calculate a sum of three columns:

```js
db.model.findAll({
  where: sequelize.where(sequelize.literal('(contstation0 + disponiblestation1 + disponiblestation2)', '<=', sequelize.col('units')))
}
```